# How to add random walk in rstanarm

Tags: r, generalized-linear-model, random-walk, stan, rstan

I have used rstanarm GLM model without the intercept like below  in R

```
GLM_Model <- stan_glm(formula = output ~ X1 +X2+X3 +X4 +X5 +X6 +X7 +X8 +X9 +X10 +
                            Y1 +Y2+Y3 +Y4 +Y5 +Y6 +Y7 +Y8 +Y9 +Y10 + 
                            Z1 +Z2+Z3 +Z4 +Z5 +Z6 +Z7 +Z8 +Z9 + Z10 + 0 , 
                data = DF,
                chains = 1, 
                iter = 5000, 
                family = gaussian(link = "log"), 
                control = list(max_treedepth = 17))
```

I got the posteriors but I wanted to add random walk on the X2, X3...X10 parameters depending on the previous ones and to be more smooth. Is there any way possible to add random walk on the predictors such that it would be great for my modelling. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The **rstanarm** R package does not support autoregressive priors. However, the **walker** R package does something close to what you want. Alternatively, you could write such a model yourself in the Stan language and estimate it with the **rstan** R package.